# How center and size a div/img of unknown size/aspect ratio within a browser window

Tags: css, image, html, center

I have created a photo gallery with a set of thumbnail images.  What I am trying to do is let the user hover over the thumbnails and pop up a  div that more or less fills the browser window with the full-size image.  I can almost do it all, but can't quite figure out how to always shrink the image to fit without cropping.  As long as the browser window is approximately the same aspect ratio as the photo, it works perfectly.  Note that I do not know a priori the size of the full image nor what aspect ratio it is.  I have experimented with using some jQuery to try and work around this  but am beginning to think it it may not be possible to this without a lot of code (in which case I will punt since this isn't that critical - it's more of a intellectual challenge at this point)

The code I have now is

```
<style>
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="popup">     
        <img width="100%" src="some_image.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I could not understand the problem at all, can you give a picture of it or jsfiddle demo

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q8sk6/.  Shrink the results window so it is not very tall and the image will begin to begin to be cropped, ditto the aspect ration (with a "portrait" image narrowing the window will begin to crop).  I don't see a way to avoid these problems, but if you don't ask...  Lots of smart people and better CSS coders than I on stackoverflow

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/q8sk6/1/ is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

rkwright, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want the image in the popup to resize based on browser width? Since you have set the image width to 100%, you need to set the width of the  popup to be a percentage of the browser window. Then, since the image is a child of the popup, it will size to 100% of the popup. Give it a try and see if it helps.

```
.popup {
   width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work either.  Ultimately, whether the image is landscape or portrait, as the browser window sinks below the aspect ratio of the image it starts cropping.  I don't know what the underlying browser logic is, but I suspect this is buried in the arcana of the box model implementation.  It doesn't seem to be surmountable.
To be clear, I have a solution that works in most (normal) cases, so this is more of an intellectual pursuit, but if the there IS an answer, I'd like to know.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the image to auto instead of 100%? I would set this in the css and not in the tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (untested)

```
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6)
}

.popup img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is worse as it distorts the image.

Comment: Distorts? It should resize while keeping aspect ratio intact: http://jsfiddle.net/8vDjH/